# Metamask authentication with passport, express, nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, metamask

I am looking for a secure Metamask Login library that seamlessly fits into the "hackathon starter project".
Since I haven't found anything useable and i'm personally not confident to just start writing my own passport strategy it would be nice if someone more experienced than me can direct my efforts.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to roll your own - there's already an existing Metamask strategy for Passport [1].

[1] https://github.com/jgostylo/passport-metamask

Comment: thx, but a 4 year old lib with only 6 stars did not give me the confidence I needed to use as auth on my website.

Comment: Understood. I would never implicitly trust a library either, especially for crypto authentication. I do recommend taking a look at the `lib/strategy.js` - it is less than 200 lines and it is pretty straightforward - even if you're going to build your own lib: https://github.com/jgostylo/passport-metamask/blob/master/lib/strategy.js